# Get param in Routing - Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, containers, slim, slim-3

How can I get the param in this case?

```
$this->get('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
  return $response->withJson($this->get('singleSelect'));
});

$this->appContainer['singleSelect'] = function ($id) {
  return $this->singleSelect($id);
};

public function singleSelect($id) {
  return $id;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Solution in my case:

```
$app->group('/id', function () {
    $this->get('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
        $this['container'] = $args; //work with $args inside the container
        return $this->singleSelect($id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand services have not access to routes parameters. All you can access is container itself but it could be tricky to get information about arguments from it (something like `$container->getRoutes()['<routename>']->getArguments()` where `<routename>` router could have subroutes, etc.)

IMHO your code should look like:

```
$container = new \Slim\Container;
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

class Example {
    public function singleSelect($id) {
        return $id;
    }
}

$container['example'] = function () {
    return new Example();
};

$app->group('/id', function () {
    $this->get('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response->withJson($this->example->singleSelect($args['id']));
    });
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Another solution is above, in my question update. Thanks.